# Getting Timeout to work

Tags: javascript, timeout, settimeout, onload, onload-event

I have a link on page and want, that after defined timeout after `onLoad` this link will be replaced with another link. I have following example code:

```js
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', changeLinks, false);

function timeout_init() {
    setTimeout('changeLinks()', 30000);
}

window.onload = changeLinks;

var _linksChanged = false;
function changeLinks() {
  if(_linksChanged) return;
  _linksChanged = true;
  var aEls = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
  for (var i = 0, aEl; aEl = aEls[i]; i++) {
    aEl.href = aEl.href.replace('https://google.com','https://yahoo.com'); 
  }
}
```

```html
<a href="https://google.com" target="_blank">link</a>
```

Problem with it: **timeout doesn't work, link is replaced immediately**.

What should be done to replace the link only after timeout binded to `onLoad`event?

Answer (score 1):

```
window.onload = function() {
  var _linksChanged = false;
  setTimeout(changeLinks, 30000);
}
function changeLinks() {
  if(_linksChanged) return;
  _linksChanged = true;
  var aEls = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
  for (var i = 0, aEl; aEl = aEls[i]; i++) {
    aEl.href = 
    aEl.href.replace('https://google.com','https://yahoo.com'); 
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> Comment Your Listener 
>   and call timeout_init() onload

```js
   // window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', changeLinks, false);

function timeout_init() {
    setTimeout('changeLinks()', 30000);
}

window.onload =  timeout_init();

var _linksChanged = false;
function changeLinks() {
  if(_linksChanged) return;
  _linksChanged = true;
  var aEls = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
  for (var i = 0, aEl; aEl = aEls[i]; i++) {
    aEl.href = aEl.href.replace('https://google.com','https://yahoo.com'); 
  }
}
```

```html
<a href="https://google.com" target="_blank">link</a>
```